# Updating tkinter label from module, what to search to learn how to do it

Tags: python, tkinter, module

A quick description to make clear what I am trying to ask as I may not be using the correct terminology.

I have made a basic gui that:
(1). gives an options menu (2). Has button that uses the options menu choice to call a module that performs a calculation that outputs a variable from the module onto the console. (3). Has a label that updates after pressing the button

However;
I would like to have a label update with a variable created from the module (rather than go to the console).

I have tried to use 'getattr' without success.

Project background - I am at the start of trying to learn my first language, I have tried and failed before, so this time I am trying to learn by creating my own project. The project is a bolted joint calculator; pick your bolt diameter from a drop-down menu, hit a button and then it will display the area as a label.

The Question: How do I call a variable that is calculated in a module?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
import boltMod2

def show(whatever):
   choice = variable.get()
   
def temp():
    temps = boltMod2.calcSize(variable.get())
    lab.config(text = "Area is " + variable.get())# i would like to read 'minA' variable from boltMod.calcsize instead
     
 
window =Tk()
window.geometry("300x200")

#oprtions for Dropdown menu
sizes = ['M6', 'M8', 'M10']
choice = sizes[0]
variable = StringVar()
variable.set(sizes[0])

#dropdown menu
popupMenu1 = OptionMenu(window, 
                           variable, 
                           *sizes, 
                           command = show)
popupMenu1.grid(column=0, row=1)

#button
myButton = Button(window,
                  text ="Calculate",
                  command = temp)
myButton.grid(column=1, row=2)
 
lab = Label(window,
            text = "select bolt ")
lab.grid(column=0, row = 3)

window.mainloop()
```

then the module "boltMod" is:

```
def calcSize(metricsize):
    print(metricsize + " is your bolt size")
    minA= 3.142*(8/2)**2 #normally values read off csv files for the 
selected bolt
    print("The area is ")
    print(minA)
```

Comment: Please create a [mre] for us. Your brief explanation gives an idea of what you have tried but for a solution/change in code, we need the basis to do this. Otherwise I suggest to research `tk.StringVar` and the option `tk.Label(.., textvariable=`

Comment: great suggestion, i have uploaded a simplified version of the code. The reason i am trying to use a module 'boltMod' is I intend to add many functions to the program, eventually I want it to be a bolter joint calculator. I will read up on getting a better understanding of StringVar. thanks again

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by calculated in a module? can you include your code?

here is some code that seems to do what you are saying (formula is just ^2 instead of whatever you are actually doing):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk() #create root GUI
root.title("Name") #Change window title
root.geometry('800x500') #Change window size


def ButtonClick(id, output): 
    if id == "o1": #if opt 1
        output.config(text="output: {}".format(1**2)) #1^2
    elif id == "o2":
        output.config(text="output: {}".format(2**2))
    else:
        output.config(text="output: {}".format(3**2))

#Main Frame---------------------------------------------------------------------
frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=225) #Create frame
frm.grid(row=0,column=0) #grid the frame
#Prompt-------------------------------
global output
output = ttk.Label(frm, text="output: ") #show prompt
output.grid(column=0, row=0)
#Buttons------------------------------
#opt1
o1 = ttk.Button(frm, text="Option 1") #add EOL directory button
o1.grid(row=1, column=0) #grid the button
o1.config(command=lambda output=output: ButtonClick("o1", output)) #reference button press function
#opt2
o2 = ttk.Button(frm, text="Option 2") #add EOL directory button
o2.grid(row=2, column=0) #grid the button
o2.config(command=lambda output=output: ButtonClick("o2", output)) #reference button press function
#opt3
o3 = ttk.Button(frm, text="Option 3") #add EOL directory button
o3.grid(row=3, column=0) #grid the button
o3.config(command=lambda output=output: ButtonClick("o3", output)) #reference button press function

root.mainloop() #execute
```

Also, you don't need the "output" to be an input to the ButtonClick() function it depends on the program's needs.

Comment: thank you for your response, i need a bit more time to go over your code, there is a lot of parts I have not come across before (config, lamda etc), I will look into them and try to get a better understanding. Thank you for your help.